# handlers and BiHandler in java : can we use the "returned" value of a BiHandler?

Tags: java, handler

I'm new with the BiConsumer in java :
my code : 
`BiConsumer<T,String> biHandler = Class:function;`
`biHandler.accept(param1,param2);`
and then I want to use the result of the **function** used in the **BiConsumer**:
but I don't know how to do it 
any ideas ? or detailed explications of the BiConsumer ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No. BiConsumer.accept doesn't return a value, even if the underlying function in your method reference does. You want to use [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) instead.